# Add-on sd card in pi?

Tags: pi-3, pi-2, hardware, sd-card

I want **add-on SD card** reader/writer/slot/controller in my raspberry pi so that i can keep OS separate from my program. Primary SD card will load OS and work normally and program & data will remain available from add-on card. Please suggest

**a) what good hardware extension or component available as add-on card for raspberry pi 3b**

**b) suitable software available.**

**OR if i can use USB Pendrive directly because i have USB slots spare. How?**

Please note: 1) I am not talking about increase SD card size and 2) not talking about creating separate partition on first SD card.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to the Raspberry Pi flavoured corner of the Stack Exchange network. I see you have read through the tour and I trust you have remembered that we are not going to necessarily say: "buy this *product code* item from this *supplier*". I do think I understand what you are asking about and will put up my attempt at an answer shortly...

Comment: What problem with pendrives do you have exactly? Cannot plug? Cannot see the files on them? Something else?

Answer (score 2):

You can use USB pendrives as much as you have free USB slots. If you want to keep programs and data on different storrages you can follow [Debian - Recommended Partitioning Scheme](https://www.debian.org/releases/jessie/amd64/apcs03.html.en).

> For new users, personal Debian boxes, home systems, and other single-user setups, a single / partition (plus swap) is probably the easiest, simplest way to go.
>   [..]
>   For multi-user systems or systems with lots of disk space, it's best to put /var, /tmp, and /home each on their own partitions separate from the / partition.

Following this you must not use separate partitions on the pendrive(s) for `/var`, `/tmp`, and `/home`. You can also use separate directories on one partition for them. You are free how to divide the data(-directories) on partition(s).

Answer (score 1):

You can use any USB device to boot a 3B, 3B+ or 3A. (some 2Bs even support that).

You can use an SD, USB stick, USB hard drive or USB SSD.

Splitting the boot drive from the base filesystem makes no sense. Adding a drive mounted at /media or /mnt is normal and commonly used.

Go and search on https://raspberrypi.org/forums where there's a massive number of posts about this. There's even a thread on there about running a read-only filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go down the route of specifically using another SDCard type unit for a secondary storage device you can, if I recall correctly, get **SPI** modules that you can wire up to that bus (three or four signal lines plus a couple for power and ground).  I would imagine that they would be available from on-line auction or retail sites.

On the other hand, USB storage devices make the same sort of thing a much easier thing to organise provided you have the available slots and space for the hub if needed as well as a USB flash drive.

Finally, the underlying SoC hardware does have support for a second SD Card interface however I am not sure that that is accessible on anything other than the Compute Module / Compute Module 3 devices which have a lot more of the connections available, it is also not clear to me either what support circuitry will need to be added to make use of that.

Update:
I have tracked down the following which might provide some useful information:

- [Wire a PCB SD card reader to USB or another interface](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/29140/36970) (marked as a duplicate of:)
- [How can I wire this SD card reader to RaspberryPi?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/28648/36970)
- [MFRC522 Not working over SPI Interface](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/50542/36970) (mentions a problem with the SPI bus that happened with some development or other in the OS a year or two back)
- [SDIO on GPIO 22-27 - what about SD-card-detect?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/38268/36970) (talks about some issues with the absence of a line to the card detect switch on the secondary SD-IO interface provided by some of the GPIO pins in an ALT mode - so has links to other details in the same subject area)

Comment: yes i was thinking for SPI module or kind of solution. I have free USB slot available but using USB Pendrive will not provide any locking/security to prevent unplug by user. SPI module can be wired and card holder can be adjusted/protected under device chassis. Thanks

Comment: From reading the SOC specs I believe there is a 2nd sdio interface - but there is no software support. Neither is there any support for the SPI interface. I did once contemplate writing a module, but decided it was not worth the effort. If should be much easier to adapt the Arduino FAT code into user space if that is helpful.

Comment: @Milliways i understand your hint that it is not worth the effort to make own software support (assuming that raspberry pi has SDIO/SPI support). Were you able to safely mount/unmount storage (sd card) to your pi or arduino using your own developed software library? I will mostly rely on this secondary sd card for read operations only.